# Keyboard stop working once windows start

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I have a Toshiba laptop with the following problem , when I access its BIOS , the keyboard works fine , but when windows 7 starts , the keyboard won't work anymore and I am stucked in the logon screen. If I hibernate and try, the keyboard starts to work.

Note that I still have the problem after reinstalling Windows 7 and that any external keyboard works fine when connected.

Comment: Do you have the latest drivers installed?

Comment: does it happen in safe mode?

Answer (score 0):

Check in 'device manager' that your built in keyboard has the correct drivers and that they are up to date.

Might also be worth checking on the Toshiba site for BIOS and Driver updates.